# Dealer reshuffles all remaining cards and the discards before flipping the river

Tags: texas-hold-em, no-limit

This situation happened. There were three remaining players.  One is all in.  Two remaining players start a side pot.  They look to the dealer to show the river.  Problem is the dealer made a mistake, he started shuffling all the remaining cards with the other player's discards.  What should have been the outcome?

Answer (score 3):

There's not much that can be done. Dealer should just complete the shuffle, cut, and deal the river card. Yes, it might be a previously discarded one, but the hand is still as mathematically fair to the players as possible under the circumstances.

Comment: While fair enough some player usaully the loser is going to go all karen on the dealer. it never turns out well. this is what buffet comps are for.